# NSUrlConnection - uploading a file and sending POST parameters

Tags: ios, post, upload, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to upload a (possibly large) file using a similar strategy I used to download a file -- i. e. use a stream.
I'm setting the HTTP body of my `NSMutableUrlRequest` to:

```
[request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

And then setting it's body stream to:

```
[request setHTTPBodyStream:inputStream];
```

But then the request's body is set to nil...

Answer (score 1):

You can only set either a `NSInputStream` *or* a `NSData` object as the request body, not both.

What you are likely trying to accomplish is setting up a multipart form request. With an NSInputStream as body, honestly, for a bunch of reasons this is a quite challenging task. I would suggest to use a third party lib.

An implementation of a network lib which can send multipart form request, having a part which has a `NSSInputStream` as part body, will require a bunch of helper classes, possibly comprising over 5000 lines of code. Look into AFNetworking, to get an idea of the required complexity when implementing multipart requests.